# fprintf and fputs ignores '\' in the string while writing it to a file

Tags: c, string, file-io

If my string contains:

```
a="abd\\aa\[1\]\\"
```

and if I try to write it to a file using `fputs` and `fprintf`, it writes the following to the file:

```
"abd\aa[1]\"
```

I want `"abd\\aa\[1\]\\"` to be written to the file. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: command line input to the c code

Comment: input is command line input to c code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` character is a special character. Try it like this:

```
a = "abd\\aa[1]\\";
```

**EDIT**

If you want `"abd\\\\aa\\[1\\]\\\\"` to be written to the file, you have to double each backslash:

```
a = "abd\\\\\\\\aa\\\\[1\\\\]\\\\\\\\";
```

Comment: the problem is the input is not in my hands if there are 5 continous backslashes in input i want all five to be in the file

Comment: So you have to double each backslash you want to write to the file. I'll update my answer.

Comment: how to do that that it this case a="{\\[}" you cannot check that if there is a '\' in this case or not

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape your `\`, like so:

```
printf("abd\\a[1]\\");
```

Or else `printf` will print `\a` which is the `BEL` character.

Answer (score 1):

Use double `\`, because `\` is the escape char:

```
a = "abd\\aa[1]\\"
```

Comment: the problem is the input is not in my hands if there are 5 continous backslashes in input i want all five to be in the file

Answer (score 0):

> I want `"abd\\\\aa\\[1\\]\\\\"` to be written to the file.

Simply double the number of back slashes.

```
fprintf(fp, "abd\\\\\\\\aa\\\\[1\\\\]\\\\\\\\" );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put a `'\'` in a string the next char will be ignored. If you put a `'\'` before a `'\'` the seconds functions will be ignored and printed.